# Normalization required in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called student data and having 20 columns in that

i have to write condition on each column like this

```
SELECT
    registered, Appeared, registered + Appeared AS col3 
FROM
    (SELECT 
     COUNT(REGDNO) AS registered, branch_code,
     SUM(CASE WHEN SUB1_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB1_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR
                   SUB2_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB1_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR
                   SUB2_GRADE <> 'Ab ' AND SUB2_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR
                   SUB3_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB3_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR 
                   SUB4_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB4_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR  
                   SUB5_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB5_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR 
                   SUB6_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB6_GRADE IS NOT NULL OR 
                   SUB7_GRADE <> 'Ab' AND SUB7_GRADE IS NOT NULL .........
```

is there any easier way
kindly help me please

Comment: The problem is not the query it is the design of the table. This really should be normalized instead. You have what is known as repeating groups which violates 1NF.

Comment: Your subject line captures it, you need to normalize your table, break out the sub1-sub7 fields into a separate table with one grade per row, then join it back to your original table,

Answer (score 1):

You could use unpivot to make all your columns into one grade column, then apply the condition on that one column.

I'm not familiar with the sql-server synthax (and I'm unable to test it right now) but in postgres, for example, it would be like that :

```
select sum(colvalue) from (
  select
    unnest(array['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) as colname,
    unnest(array[col1, col2, col3]) as colvalue
  from my_table) x
where colvalue <> 'Ab' and colvalue is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using unpivot to check if any of the columns are populated and <> 'Ab'. Note that <>'Ab' returns false for Nulls anyway:

```
create table rr (a char(2), b char(2), c char(2), d char(2), e char(2), f char(2))

insert into rr values (null,'aa',null,null,'ac','ab')

Select sum(iif(u.[cols]<>'AB', 1,0))
from rr s
unpivot
(
  [cols]
  for [vals] in (a, b, c, d, e, f)
) u;
```